# xsl:sort not working as expected

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

**This is my xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
                doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt">
            <head>
                <title>teste</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//produtos"/>


            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="produto">

        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>

        <xsl:variable name="nr" select="count(//avaliacao[@produto = $id])"/>

        <xsl:variable name="stars" select="sum(//avaliacao[@produto = $id]/@stars)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="media" select="$stars div $nr"/>

        <xsl:if test="$media &gt; 2">

            <xsl:for-each select="//produto[@id = $id]">
                <xsl:sort select="string($media)" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="$media"/>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>


        </xsl:template>



        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is my XML (it's a bit large):

```
        <produtos>

        <produto id="P01">
            <nome>Powerbank</nome>
            <descricao>Nova.</descricao>
            <caracteristicas nome="Powerbank" valor="19,99"/>
            <preco>19.99</preco>
            <data_ins>2017/10/16</data_ins>
            <transportadora empresa="CTT"/>
            <transportadora empresa="SEUR"/>
            <links_f href="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1YGZkLXXXXXb8XFXXq6xXFXXXr/Original-DOCA-font-b-Power-b-font-font-b-Ban-b-font-Real-5000Mah-Li-polymer.jpg"/>              
            <vendedor id="U07"/>
        </produto>

                <avaliacoes>

            <avaliacao produto="P04" autor="U02" stars="5"/>
            <avaliacao produto="P03" autor="U02" stars="4"/>
            <avaliacao produto="P01" autor="U01" stars="5"/>
            <avaliacao produto="P07" autor="U03" stars="5"/>
            <avaliacao produto="P08" autor="U01" stars="4"/>
            <avaliacao produto="P09" autor="U01" stars="2"/>

        </avaliacoes>
```

This is just a sample of my XML, the original is 400 lines large.

Basically my problem is that I'm trying to make an average of the stars given to a certain product and then sort the products with an average greater than 2 stars.

Right now my XHTML output is:

```
5 3 5 5 4
```

instead of:

```
5 5 5 4 3
```

*What is wrong with my XSLT?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `xsl:for-each` is in a template matching `produto` but all it is going to do is select the exact same (single) product, so there is nothing to sort.

To do the sorting, you should do so in the code that selects `produto` in the first place. (Which you don't actually have)

But to make things simpler, consider using a key to look up the `avaliacao` elements.

```
<xsl:key name="avaliacao" match="avaliacao" use="@produto" />
```

Then you can have an `xsl:apply-templates` to select `produto` that can do both the sort, and the filtering...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//produto[sum(key('avaliacao', @id)/@stars) div count(key('avaliacao', @id)) gt 2]">
    <xsl:sort select="sum(key('avaliacao', @id)/@stars) div count(key('avaliacao', @id))" order="descending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"
            doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" />

    <xsl:key name="avaliacao" match="avaliacao" use="@produto" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt">
            <head>
                <title>teste</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//produto[sum(key('avaliacao', @id)/@stars) div count(key('avaliacao', @id)) gt 2]">
                    <xsl:sort select="sum(key('avaliacao', @id)/@stars) div count(key('avaliacao', @id))" order="descending" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="produto">
        <xsl:variable name="nr" select="count(key('avaliacao', @id))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="stars" select="sum(key('avaliacao', @id)/@stars)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="media" select="$stars div $nr"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$media"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Right now xsl:sort has an error that says "expected xs:string got xs:integer". Then I added string(sum(key(.....) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Got it, you forgot the &gt; in the apply-templates. Thank you very much for the reply!